# What is the correct IP syntax to block an IP range (subnet) with Varnish acl unwanted?

Tags: ip, acl, varnish, subnet

Trying to configure my Varnish .vcl file as I need to block a bot accessing my site and messing up my Analytics weekly.

This is what I have, but it's not working.

I need to block all subnet IP. This syntax used to work before I installed Varnish in .htaccess. Can someone please point me to the IP syntax that works for Varnish?

```
acl unwanted {
 "45.32"/24;
 "45.76"/24;
 "45.77";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip ~ unwanted) {
        return(synth(403, "Access denied"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of an IP address in that range you want to block. It looks like your CIDR is a bit too short. Example: `45.32.12.0/24`. Based on that, I'll correct your VCL example.

Comment: I would like to ban, for example, 45.32.x.x and as far as I have found out it should be done 45.32.0.0/16. Can you confirm that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the VCL you need to ban these subnets:

```
acl unwanted {
 "45.32.0.0"/16;
 "45.76.0.0"/16
 "45.77.0.0"/16
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip ~ unwanted) {
        return(synth(403, "Access denied"));
    }
}
```